# Is there a list of all possible WordPress URL's?

Tags: templates, urls

I'm looking for a way to find out how my WordPress site handles various incoming requests, some of which I have not written templates for.

For example, there are a number of archive views (year, author, etc.) that I'm currently not using, but I still want to have control over what is displayed if a user (or attacker…) would "guess" such a URL.

I can think of a few of them, but would ideally want a complete list I could go through, testing each URL against my site and evaluate the result.

Is there such a list available?

Comment: What about a Sitemap plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for: http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png

Comment: Not exactly. That is the file end of things, I'm trying to figure out the URL side. So, for example, there is the `/category/xyz` type of URL, or `/tag/abc`, or `/postname/feed`, and so on.

Comment: I don't think that such a list is possible, except one that you might generate dynamically from your site. As brasofilo suggested, you might try a sitemap plugin. Even then, there are many possible ways to access each object.

I think the best thing to do is use the Template Hierarchy image and extrapolate the possible urls for each object, which will depend on your rewrite tags. If you follow each branch from left to right, you'll hit all of the default objects.